# How do I start using Gitlab-CI in Gitlab Omnibus edition?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have installed Gitlab Omnibus gitlab-7.4.3_omnibus.5.1.0.ci-1.el6.x86_64.rpm on CentOS 6.6. I have a few projects created and working fine but I would like to try using the continuous integration features. I don't know where to start and documentation/tutorials are thin on the ground.
I have found the following files that do not appear in an older Gitlab omnibus install I have:

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-ci-rake
/usr/bin/gitlab-ci-rails
```

I presume I need to do something with these? But do I need a configuration file first? 
In my projects (Settings > Services > Gitlab CI) I can see there are options for Active, Token and Project Url but I do not know what to put in these fields. 
Any help to get me started on CI would be appreciated. Cheers,jonny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recently installed the omnibus GitLab 7.6.2 release which has GitLab CI 5.3 built in. I had the same question. Here's how we got it working.

We're using a single secured server over https; single ip for both gitlab and gitalb-ci hosts.
We have dns entries for both host names to a single ip. (Done with an alias for the ci server I think). We have two ssl certificates one for each hostname.

We have the following lines at the top of the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb script (found by searching the gitlab site for rb file setup details):

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.edu'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true

ci_external_url 'https://gitlab-ci.example.edu'
ci_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
```

For http, leave out the nginx statements.

If gitlab-ci url displays the gitlab site contents then the ci_nginx statement needs to be corrected.